# What does "result.status_code == 200" in Python mean?

Tags: python, http

In this little piece of code, what is the fourth line all about?

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
url = "http://www.google.com/"
result = urlfetch.fetch(url)
if result.status_code == 200:
    doSomethingWithResult(result.content)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a HTTP status code, it means "OK" (EG: The server successfully answered the http request).

[See a list of them here on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Answer (score 8):

Whoever wrote that should have used a constant instead of a magic number. The httplib module has all the http response codes.

E.g.:

```
>>> import httplib
>>> httplib.OK
200
>>> httplib.NOT_FOUND
404
```

Comment: HTTP return codes are constant rather than a magic number. They won't magically change tomorrow ...

Comment: @X-Istence, you don't appear to know what the term "magic number" means. A magic number, in this context, is a numeric literal that appears in the code without explanation.

Answer (score 6):

200 is the HTTP status code for "OK", a successful response.  (Other codes you may be familiar with are 404 Not Found, 403 Forbidden, and 500 Internal Server Error.)

See [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) for more information.